# WatchOS 2 App Group not sharing NSUserDefaults to Watch Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I understand that in watchOS 2 you cannot write to shared app groups, however you **can** read from them, according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Settings.html):

> In watchOS 2, your WatchKit extension can only read values from the
>   database.

I'm writing `studentUsername` and `studentPassword` to my group identified as `group.com.spcc.BlahBlah`. Both the WatchKit Extension and main iOS app have the app group capability turned on.

I can read my two values from `group.com.spcc.BlahBlah` with the following code from my iOS app, but not my Interface Controller in the Watch App Extension in the `awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?)` function:

```
let studentUsername = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.spcc.BlahBlah")?.objectForKey("studentUsername")! as! String
let studentPassword = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.spcc.BlahBlah")?.objectForKey("studentPassword")! as! String
```

Using that code in the Watch App Extension returns both my values as nil. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Checkout my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34256918/5576310) it explains why and how to solve your issue.

Comment: @RashwanL Thanks. Is it me, or have Apple been quite ambiguous in their documentation here?

Comment: This has not been that clear and it´s definitely not you :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH6-SW9

Comment: @TonyMkenu I stand corrected, thanks for this reference